# INotifyPropertyChanged simple issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 in my project. I have created a partial class with the exact same namespace as my Entities and added custom properties in it. How do i raise notification in the setter of these properties?

When i write PropertyChanged() i don't get any Intellisense help from VS2010 whatsoever and even the code doesn't compile. If I explicitly implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my partial class it doesn't let me raise the event in the setter of my property. I then inherit my partial class also explicitly from EntityObject:

```
 public partial class Photo : EntityObject
    {
        private byte[] _photoByteArr = null;
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public byte[] PhotoByteArr
        {
            get
            {
                return _photoByteArr;
            }
            set
            {
                _photoByteArr = value;
                //tried to put ReportPropertyChanged("PhotoByteArr"); here but it doesn't //work and gives error that its is not valid.
            }
        }
```

How do I raise property changed notifications in these custom properties?

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating your custom partial class in the same assembly?

From MSDN:

> All partial-type definitions meant to
>   be parts of the same type must be
>   defined in the same assembly and the
>   same module (.exe or .dll file).
>   Partial definitions cannot span
>   multiple modules.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx